# how to make toplevel the main window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

how to transfer a user to the toplevel window when he tries to switch to the main window. and the main window should be inactive.

I tried to find the answer on the internet, but I never found it.

I need functionality, for example, when opening explorer, select a file/folder and try to switch to the application that opened this window.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the `grab_set` method? It's not clear without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the grab.set() method to set the focus on the top window

```py
from tkinter import *


def new_window():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("New Window")
    top.grab_set()


root = Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
btn = Button(root, text="Click", command=new_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```